# Correct Usage of :not() selector

Tags: css

I want to apply certain styling to some, but not all, links within a certain div.  The structure is as follows:

```
<div class="feed-post">
    <a href="#">This is the link I want to style</a>
    <a class="internal-link" href="#">This is the link I DON'T want to style</a>
</div>
```

I don't have direct access to the HTML so I cannot simply add a class to the first link.  I've tried a few combinations of selectors already, such as:

`.feed-post a:not(.internal-link)`

I really don't understand why the above selector doesn't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: Solved! Thanks all for the help.  It was being targeted by a different selector.  When I made that one more specific, my unintended styling went away.

Comment: Show us an example with the full CSS. What you posted works - https://jsfiddle.net/fued2kL0/ Are you sure there is not another style that's more specific, overriding what you have?

Comment: @disinfor Ah, you're right.  It's getting its style from another class.  I will keep working.  Thank you for the insight!

Comment: Just make your selector more specific and you should be good to go! Voting to close as this was more generic than the `not:` selector and can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

You're using it correctly, it works as intended, unless the style is overriden somewhere else in your CSS.

Check the below snippet.

```css
.feed-post a:not(.internal-link){
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="feed-post">
    <a href="#">This is the link I want to style</a>
    <a class="internal-link" href="#">This is the link I DON'T want to style</a>
</div>
```